Ruby add/subtract seconds, minutes, hours only
How can I start with a HH:MM:SS Ruby string like "00:00:08" and combine it with "-00:00:06" to get the difference, which would be "00:00:02" in this case?
Anything I try to look up involves converting to a DateTime, but do I really need to involve days or years to find out the relative difference?

You don't need to, but using DateTime seems the simplest way

I guess I don't understand how to model it with DateTime

@kraftydevil: Time.strptime('00:00:08', '%H:%M:%s')-Time.strptime('00:00:06', '%H:%M:%s')? Returns 2.0, which you can convert back to a time, or just do the simple math to format it as a string yourself.

@ShadowRanger %s is number of seconds since epoch, it'll override everything else. use %S.

@Alex: Ah whoops. This is what I get for not rechecking the docs. Thanks for the correction.

To balance readability, testability and compactness I propose the following three methods. I don't think the complexity of the calculation justifies the creation of a class.
Convert strings to seconds
def str_to_seconds(str)
  tot = str.match(/(\d{2,}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?!\d)/)
           .captures
           .zip([3600, 60, 1])
           .sum { |s,d| s.to_i * d }
  str[0] == '-' ? -tot : tot
end

Some examples:
puts "      str        str_to_seconds(str)"
puts "------------------------------------"
["00:00:07", "00:00:37", "00:02:07", "00:58:02", "02:00:07",
 "06:01:02", "50:00:07", "130:00:07", "-130:00:07", "00:00:011"].each do |str|
  print "%11s" % str
  puts "   %15d" % str_to_seconds(str)
end

      str        str_to_seconds(str)
------------------------------------
   00:00:07                 7
   00:00:37                37
   00:02:07               127
   00:58:02              3482
   02:00:07              7207
   06:01:02             21662
   50:00:07            180007
  130:00:07            468007
 -130:00:07           -468007
   00:00:011
  NoMethodError: undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass

Convert seconds to strings
def seconds_to_str(secs)
  abs_secs = secs.abs
  hrs, abs_secs = abs_secs.divmod(3600)
  mins, abs_secs = abs_secs.divmod(60)
  str = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % [hrs, mins, abs_secs]
  secs < 0 ? "-#{str}" : str
end

Some examples:
puts "      secs     seconds_to_str(secs)"
puts "-----------------------------------"
[7, 37, 127, 3482, -7207, 21662, 180007, 468007, -468007].each do |secs|
  puts "%11d   %14s" % [secs, seconds_to_str(secs)]
end

      secs     seconds_to_str(secs)
-----------------------------------
          7         00:00:07
         37         00:00:37
        127         00:02:07
       3482         00:58:02
      -7207        -02:00:07
      21662         06:01:02
     180007         50:00:07
     468007        130:00:07
    -468007       -130:00:07

Compute desired result
def compute(str1, str2)
  seconds_to_str(str_to_seconds(str1) + str_to_seconds(str2))
end

Some examples:
puts "    str1        str2     compute(str1, sz)"
puts "------------------------------------------"
[[ "00:00:45", "00:00:17"], [" 00:00:45", "-00:00:17"],
 ["-00:00:45", "00:00:17"], ["-00:00:45", "-00:00:17"],
 [" 16:12:05", "13:13:06"], [ "16:12:05", "-13:13:06"],
 ["-16:12:05", "13:13:06"], ["-16:12:05", "-13:13:06"],].each do |str1, str2|
  puts "%10s  %10s      %10s" % [str1, str2, compute(str1, str2)]
end

    str1        str2     compute(str1, sz)
------------------------------------------
  00:00:45    00:00:17        00:01:02
  00:00:45   -00:00:17        00:00:28
 -00:00:45    00:00:17       -00:00:28
 -00:00:45   -00:00:17       -00:01:02
  16:12:05    13:13:06        29:25:11
  16:12:05   -13:13:06        02:58:59
 -16:12:05    13:13:06       -02:58:59
 -16:12:05   -13:13:06       -29:25:11


@engineersmnky, thanks for your eagle eye coming to bear on my answer yet again. I did an edit.

Make a class to parse your string into seconds, define any operations you need like + and -, and format back to string representation from seconds. Having negative sign as part of the string needs a little extra hand holding:
class Tyme
  def initialize str
    @negative = str.start_with?("-")
    str = str.sub(/-/, "")
    @h, @m, @s = str.split(":").map(&:to_i)
    @total = @h * 3600 + @m * 60 + @s
  end

  def total
    @negative ? -@total : @total
  end

  def +(other)
    format total + other.total
  end

  def -(other)
    format total - other.total
  end

  private

  def format total_seconds
    minutes, seconds = total_seconds.abs.divmod(60)
    hours, minutes = minutes.divmod(60)
    fmt = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % [hours, minutes, seconds]
    total_seconds.negative? ? "-#{fmt}" : fmt
  end
end

>> Tyme.new("00:00:08") + Tyme.new("-00:00:02")
=> "00:00:06"
>> Tyme.new("00:00:08") - Tyme.new("00:00:02")
=> "00:00:06"
>> Tyme.new("00:00:08") - Tyme.new("-00:00:02")
=> "00:00:10"


@Stefan refactor
class Duration
  def self.parse str
    negative = str.start_with?("-") ? -1 : 1
    str = str.sub(/-/, "")
    h, m, s = str.split(":").map(&:to_i)
    total = negative * (h * 3600 + m * 60 + s)
    new total
  end

  def initialize seconds
    @seconds = seconds
  end

  attr_reader :seconds

  def +(other)
    Duration.new seconds + other.seconds
  end

  def -(other)
    Duration.new seconds - other.seconds
  end

  def to_s
    minutes, seconds = @seconds.abs.divmod(60)
    hours, minutes = minutes.divmod(60)
    fmt = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % [hours, minutes, seconds]
    @seconds.negative? ? "-#{fmt}" : fmt
  end

  def inspect
    "#<Duration #{to_s}>"
  end
end

>> Duration.parse("00:00:08") + Duration.parse("-00:00:02")
=> #<Duration 00:00:06>
>> Duration.parse("00:00:08") - Duration.parse("00:00:02")
=> #<Duration 00:00:06>
>> Duration.parse("00:00:08") - Duration.parse("-00:00:02")
=> #<Duration 00:00:10>


Some suggestions: make initialize take the number of seconds and define a separate self.parse for parsing strings. Change + and - to return new Tyme instances instead of strings. Rename format to to_s / inspect. (maybe rename Tyme to Duration)

If you wish to avoid DateTime you can manually parse the time and convert to seconds.
def to_seconds(str)
  neg = str =~ /^\-/

  str = str.sub(/^\-/, '')
    
  (neg ? -1 : 1) * str
    .split(':')
    .map(&:to_i)
    .reverse
    .each_with_index
    .sum  { |x, i| x * 60 ** i }
end

Adding or subtracting numbers of seconds is easy. At this point you just need to reverse the process to revert to a formatted hours/minutes/seconds timestamp.

Here is another option:
def time_to_seconds(time)
  ord,hours,min,seconds = time.scan(/(-|\+)?(\d+):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/).flatten
  result = [3600,60,1].zip([hours,min,seconds].map(&:to_i)).sum{|a| a.reduce(:*)}
  result.send("#{ord || '+'}@")
end 

def diff_times(t1,t2)
  diff_seconds = time_to_seconds(t1) + time_to_seconds(t2)
  ord = '-' if diff_seconds < 0
  result = [3600,60,1].map {|e| r,diff_seconds = diff_seconds.abs.divmod(e); r }
  sprintf "#{ord}%02d:%02d:%02d", *result
end 

t1 = "00:00:08"
t2 = "-00:00:06"

diff_times(t1,t2)
#=> "00:00:02"

First we convert each time into seconds using a regex to capture each group of hours, minutes, and seconds, accounting for + or -.
Then we add them together to get the duration in seconds.
Finally we convert them back into an Array of [hours, minutes,seconds] and use Kernel#sprintf to format the output String
